# Slow add-on: ~13k named ranges in empty document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've created Google Apps Script for Google Documents which uses [`NamedRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/named-range) for keeping track of the text inserted by the script. The script is bound to the Document, because I use methods, which would otherwise be restricted.

I though it would be a good idea to share the add-on with others via Google Add-on Marketplace, so I've published the script and while I wait for it being evaluated, the script started to behave strangely.

Yesterday, the Google Drive service had some problems and since then, my script runs very slowly, it sometimes throws `Service unavailable: Docs` or `Exceeded maximum execution time`. I started to debug my script and found out, that calling:

```
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getNamedRanges()
```

returns enormous amount of named ranges. Even after truncating my test document with <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd>, there is still over 13,000 named ranges in returned array.

Do you have any explanation for that?

Comment: It would seem that your script created a lot of named ranges for some reason. I don't know what other explanation you are expecting.

Comment: @Minestrone This was most probably caused by google evaluating process. The evaluating process was ended yesterday and since then my document works OK once again. I assume they made huge number of named ranges for testing performance and it somehow bubbled into my document.